# Comparing AUC-PR between groups with different baselines

Tags: predictive-models, model-evaluation, group-differences, precision-recall, average-precision

So I know that [the area under the precision-recall curve is often a more useful metric than AUROC when dealing with highly imbalanced datasets](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0118432). However, while AUROC can easily be used to compare classifier performance between different groups (since values are on the same scale), AUC-PR has the "problem" that baselines may differ between groups: a random classifier will have an AUC-PR that is equal to the baseline incidence in that group, i.e., the fraction of positive outcomes.

Given this knowledge, how can one compare AUC-PR values between groups with different baselines? Obviously, one cannot simply compare the absolute values since they are on different scales: a value of 0.5 might indicate a fully random classifier in one group (with incidence 50%) and a pretty good classifier in another group (with incidence of, say, 10%).

One obvious idea would be to normalize AUC-PR values to the range [0,1] by subtracting the baseline and dividing by (1-baseline) in each group. Would it be a good idea to use such normalized AUC-PR values for comparing classifier performance between groups? Are there drawbacks? Do people do this? Are there other, better ways?

Comment: Have a look at AUPR gain curves. https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2015/hash/33e8075e9970de0cfea955afd4644bb2-Abstract.html

Comment: @GeorgM.Goerg Excellent suggestion, thanks! I should have guessed that Peter had written something good on the subject. ;-) Will try to write up a short answer based on that in the next days (unless you want to do it!).